# Using mysql JOIN to select data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables representing users and their friends: `users` and `friendships`

- `users` has `id` and `name`
- `friendships` has `id`, `friend1_id` and `friend2_id`

By searching a user's name, I want to get their associated friends' names.

Comment: did you test the answer that you accepted? Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oD5vzNH9H7tXQMR4HJDint/2 it does not return your expected results.

Comment: @forpas it works as expected. The relationships are one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT u2.name from users u1
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u1.name = [your_name_to_search]
INNER JOIN friendships fs 
ON u2.id = fs.friend2_id AND u1.id = fs.friend1_id
```

**Explanation**:

I used 2 joins in this approach: the first `users` *self join* will assure you take the `id` corresponding to `[your_name_to_search]`, and then the second join with `friendships` will extract the names of `friend_2_id` matching with the `friend_1_id` taken from the first join.

You can test this approach [on this db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oD5vzNH9H7tXQMR4HJDint/0)

Answer (score 1):

Join `friendships` to 2 copies of `users`.
The 1st copy will be filtered for the user name that you search for and the 2nd will return all the user's friends:

```
select uf.name
from users u
inner join friendships fs on u.id in (fs.friend1_id, fs.friend2_id)
inner join users uf on uf.id in (fs.friend1_id, fs.friend2_id) and uf.id <> u.id
where u.name = ?
```

Replace `?` with the name of the user whose friends you want in the results.